# How Spring Ioc container interacts with Tomcat container

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, ioc-container

I am familiar with the Spring Framework and have done some work in it.

In one of my interviews, I was asked "there is a web application deployed in *Apache Tomcat*; tell me how does the "Tomcat container" (used for servlets) interact with "Spring IoC container" (used for Spring beans)?"

I couldn't understand what the interviewer meant by that and was left speechless. Can someone please clarify what this question was about and what a reasonable answer to it might be?

Answer (score 7):

A spring web-app will define a Spring Dispatcher Servlet in its config, the apache tomcat container will initialise this servlet, the dispatcher servlet in turn initialises the application context. There is no direct interaction between the tomcat container and the Spring IOC container.

Comment: Yes. DispatcherServlet and I think also the `ContextLoaderListener` as well. Because we can opt to use `DispatcherServlet` based on MVC requirement.

Answer (score 3):

There are two primary aspects of linking Spring with Servlets. First you have to load a Spring application context, and second you need to expose those Spring-loaded objects to the Servlet. There are many ways to do this, and frameworks like [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/servlet-transport.html) have built-in support for Spring.

But one of the most basic mechanisms is to use a [ContextLoaderListener](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html) to load the application context and a [HttpRequestHandlerServlet](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/HttpRequestHandlerServlet.html) to initialize the servlet.

Here's a simple example:

web.xml:

```
<web-app>
...
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>servletBean</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
...
</web-app>
```

And in /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml:

```
<beans>
..
  <!-- Note: YourServletClass must implement HttpRequestHandler -->
  <bean id="servletBean" name="servletBean" class="yournamespace.YourServletClass">
    ...
  </bean>
...
</beans>
```

Comment: Thanks..but it seems to be for one servlet..what if I have multiple servlets in my application which need Spring loaded objects?

Comment: The HttpRequestHandlerServlet uses the servlet-name to locate the bean to act as the Servlet. So if you have multiple Servlets just use multiple instances of HttpRequestHandlerServlet with separate servlet-names, and map each to different beans in your applicationContext.xml.

Comment: Thanks a lot..I am able to run :)

Answer (score 3):

Spring apps declare a `DispatcherServlet` as part of the application configuration. The DipatcherServlet is a child class of `HttpServlet` and hence represents the servlet for the container. The `DispatcherServlet` also creates a `WebApplicationContext`. Spring maintains an IOC container for each WebApplicationContext (there can be multiple servlets in an app). There can also be a root `ApplicationContext`, which is created by the `ContextLoaderListener`. The root ApplicationContext is a parent of all WebApplicationContext(s) in a web app. The IOC container of ApplicationContext is available to all WebApplicationContext(s).

The `ServletContext` remains the single mode of interaction for all web containers.