# Hibernate + Spring + Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, tomcat

I'm looking for some literature (Books or tutorials) that goes into great details about how those components work together. I know there are a lot of articles that show how to quickly set up an application, but that's not what I'm looking for.

I already have a basic understanding and would like to expand it.

Thank you very much for you help

Comment: Can you be a bit more speciffic ? Are you looking for conceptional information (e.g. like provided in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28040529/what-is-the-difference-between-servlet-container-and-spring-container) or are you looking for technical topics (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509861/how-spring-ioc-container-interacts-with-tomcat-container)

Comment: Your question is off-topic: It's seeking recommendations for books, software libraries, or other off-site resources. The Spring documentation is what you should read.

Comment: I can recommend this course for you. https://www.udemy.com/course/spring-framework-5-beginner-to-guru/

Comment: udemy is your best opportunity. There are hundreds of courses about that.

Answer (score 1):

Spring is (a big) java framework and Hibernate is layer over database, Tomcat is a Servlet/JSP container, so it's very broad subject

The right way is to use [Spring boot](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-hibernate) to add Hibernate

> ```
> <dependency>
> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> This dependency includes JPA API, JPA Implementation, JDBC and other needed libraries. **Since the default JPA implementation is Hibernate, this dependency is actually enough to bring it in as well**

Add [Tomcat as an embedded server](https://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-with-embedded-servers-tomcat-jetty)

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
>   <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
>   <scope>compile</scope>
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> Starter Tomcat brings in all the dependencies need to run Tomcat as an embedded server.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have basic knowledge in Spring+Hibernate+Tomcat

Spring Projects provides very details documentation with examples:

- [Spring COre](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html)
- [Spring Testing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html)
- [Data Access](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html)
- [Web on Servlet Stack](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html)
- [Integration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html)
- [Language Support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/languages.html)
- [Web on Reactive Stack](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html)
- [Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/)
- [Spring Data](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data)
- [Spring Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/)
- Rest of the project and its details you will get from [Spring Projects](https://spring.io/projects)